# What annotations should i use to create indexes using Ebean?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I would like to create indexes on certain columns in my table. I am using Ebean and Play-java. I was wondering what the right annotations are for creating an index on a column/table.

Has anyone used JPA annotations for indexing successfully?

NOTE: I know that I can always manually create indexes and not bother about annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ebean has @Index. Note that in version 6.5.1 support was enhanced - https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/368

Single column example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_basic")
public class EBasic {

  ...

  @Index
  String name;
```

Multi-column example:

```
@Index(columnNames = {"last_name","first_name"})
@Entity
public class Contact {
```